# .NET delete a file that doesnt exist?

Tags: .net, file-io

I want to delete a file that may or may not exist. I write

```
try { File.Delete(temp); } catch { }
```

Is there an easier way? Also I realize this ignores other exceptions as well but i dont care in this case.

Comment: If you *realize this ignores other exceptions as well but you dont care in this case* then your code seems fine. But would you tell the user about *Invalid file path*, or about *Unauthorized access* to the file?

Comment: File.Delete does not throw excpetion if file does not exist.

Comment: Faisal: Really? I thought thats how it was before maybe i did something weird.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [File.Delete doesn't throw error when the file doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884807/file-delete-doesnt-throw-error-when-the-file-doesnt-exist)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No need for the `try catch` block to handle a non-existant file. The `File.Delete` method does not throw an exception if the file does not exist. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete.aspx):

> If the file to be deleted does not
>   exist, no exception is thrown.

Comment: I'd usually vote that up for brevity, but that is not to say that Delete never throws an exception, If the path specified is invalid, for example, Delete will raise an exception.

Comment: There are a few other exceptions to watch for, e.g. if the files in use or it's an XP or before system and there's an open file handle.

Comment: Edited for clarity about why the `try catch` block in the question does not accomplish what the questioner thought it did.

Comment: Corrected. What happened was i forgot to create the folder first where the temp file usually resides in. Thus the exception. Oops.

Answer (score 6):

```
try
{
    if(File.Exists(temp))
       File.Delete(temp);

}
catch(IOException e)
{
   // file is in use
}
catch(UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
{
   // read only
   // no permissions
}
```

More can be found on the MSDN page for [File.Delete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(SYSTEM.IO.FILE.DELETE);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION%3dV3.5%22);k(DevLang-CSHARP)&rd=true)

Comment: Ha, did not know that. But defensive programming, and in case you want to do other stuff if the file exists (like remove from a list)

Comment: In the spirit of defensive programming, doing a catch for `UnauthorizedAccessException`s or `IOException`s would probably be warranted.

Comment: just want to notice that the code in the `try` body is affected to race condition

Comment: it is indeed, how would you get around it? You need to check the file exists before you can do anything to the file? Is that not correct?

Comment: @PostMan: No you don't ;-) Just try the action in question, and deal with the error (exception) when it occurs. Or do check before you attempt - eventually presenting a "better" error message - but be prepared that the actual operation may still fail later.