# File.Delete doesn't throw error when the file doesn't exist

Tags: c#, .net, file, windows-server-2008

Strange problem occurs on the production platform (64 bit win 2008 server).
It is connected with `File.Exists` and `File.Delete` methods...

On test platform in debug (win xp), etc it works fine. On Server 2008 for the first few times
`File.Exists` reported `true` for the file which didn't exist ...

When I Was doing further tests `File.Exists` finally reported false for the file which didn't exist.
But `File.Delete` hadn't thrown any error when attempting to delete the file which didn't exists ...

What is happening ... ?

I read somewhere that system virtualation could mess the things up ... but hasn't found any file in: `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\VirtualStore`

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`File.Delete` on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete.aspx):

```
public static void Delete(string path)
```

> If the file to be deleted does not exist, no exception is thrown.

So. it's deliberated....  no `true` \ `false` and no exceptions, just delete the file if it exist.

Note about `File.Exist`:

```
public static bool Exists(string path)
```

**Return Value**  Type: System.Boolean

> **true** if the caller has the required permissions and path contains the name of an existing file; otherwise, **false**. This method also returns **false** if path is Nothing, an invalid path, or a zero-length string. If the caller does not have sufficient permissions to read the specified file, **no exception is thrown and the method returns false regardless of the existence of path.**

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx)

Comment: My mistake, when I Was testing the File.Delete method on my machine the error I got was that it couldn't find the path specified in the parameter, that's why I got the impression that it is because the file didn't exist. But obviously it works as you wrote @gdoron. Thank You.

Comment: Yes, if the directory part of the path does not exist, an exception is thrown.

Comment: Yup, to double down, if the directory is bad, it will throw an exception. - Which is a bit strange.. But if it had to validate the dir too, it would take longer.