# C# File.Delete not behaving as expected

Tags: c#

Apologies if the question was not clear enough. 
I am rephrasing it again..
I am trying to delete the junk files in the server, in my case Shortcut files (.lnk) etc that came into the server accidentally.

Code:

```
 try
     {
        //************** need to remove the Thumbs.db,.DS_Store and other sort 
       of junk files
                //Files to Delete
                if ((_configurationService.FilesToDelete != null) && 
      (_configurationService.FilesToDelete != ""))
                {
                    string filesToDelete = _configurationService.FilesToDelete;
                    string[] files;

                    if (filesToDelete.Contains(",")) // multiple files
                    {
                        files = filesToDelete.Split(',');
                        foreach (string f in files)
                        {
                            string[] listoffiles = 
     Directory.GetFiles(sourceDirectoryPath, f, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
                            foreach (string s in listoffiles)
                            {
                                _logger.Debug("The list of files to delete: " + 
     s);
                                fi = new FileInfo(s);
                                File.SetAttributes(s, FileAttributes.Normal);
                                File.Delete(s);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else // single file
                    {
                        string[] listoffiles = 
     Directory.GetFiles(sourceDirectoryPath, filesToDelete, 
     SearchOption.AllDirectories);
                        foreach (string s in listoffiles)
                        {
                            _logger.Debug("The list of files to delete: " + s);
                            fi = new FileInfo(s);
                            File.SetAttributes(s, FileAttributes.Normal);
                            File.Delete(s);
                        }
                    }

                }

                //Extensions to delete  
                if ((_configurationService.ExtensionsToDelete != null) && 
      (_configurationService.ExtensionsToDelete != ""))
                {
                    string extnToDelete = 
     _configurationService.ExtensionsToDelete;

                    if (extnToDelete.Contains(","))
                    {
                        string[] extn = extnToDelete.Split(',');
                        foreach (string e in extn)
                        {
                            string[] listofextn = 
     Directory.GetFiles(sourceDirectoryPath, e, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
                            foreach (string s in listofextn)
                            {
                                _logger.Debug("The list of files to delete: " + 
     s);
                                fi = new FileInfo(s);
                                File.SetAttributes(s, FileAttributes.Normal);
                                File.Delete(s);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        string[] listofextn = 
     Directory.GetFiles(sourceDirectoryPath, extnToDelete, 
     SearchOption.AllDirectories);
                        foreach (string s in listofextn)
                        {
                            _logger.Debug("The list of files to delete: " + s);
                            fi = new FileInfo(s);
                            File.SetAttributes(s, FileAttributes.Normal);
                            File.Delete(s);
                        }
                    }

                }
                //*******************************
                //##############################################################
     ##
      }
      catch(IOException ex)
            {
                _logger.Exception(ex.InnerException, "IO Exception/Pathtoolong 
      exception");
                return Task.FromResult(true);
            }
            catch(System.Security.SecurityException sx)
            {
                _logger.Exception(sx.InnerException, "Security Exception");
                return Task.FromResult(true);
            }
            catch (System.UnauthorizedAccessException sx)
            {
                _logger.Exception(sx.InnerException, "UnAuth Access Exception");
                return Task.FromResult(true);
            }
            catch (System.ArgumentException sx)
            {
                _logger.Exception(sx.InnerException, "Arg Exception");
                return Task.FromResult(true);
            }
            catch (System.NotSupportedException sx)
            {
                _logger.Exception(sx.InnerException, "Notsupported Exception");
                return Task.FromResult(true);
            }
```

Here :
FilesToDelete = Thumbs.db,Shortcut to gilsbrg.woff.lnk
ExtensionsToDelete = *.db,*.DS_Store,*.lnk
are config entries for the variety of junk file extensions.

So to check the path of the files i logged the same into the DB and the path were exactly right. Even then the files are not getting deleted via the code.[File path logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIjin.jpg)

To check if the code is returning an error i tried to catch all possible errors via the catch block 
But it dint flow through any of them indicating that there was no errors.

This code is part of a Azure Worker Role which tries to delete the files from the server machine. Is this something related to permission of the file or something ??

Any guidance would be really helpful.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you tried using the absolute path to the file?

Comment: Use the absolute path, for sure. The current file path depends on the working directory (where you run your code from).

Comment: What path are you using? Files (including links) on the desktop can come from different physical directories (e.g. the user's desktop and the "shared" desktop for all users)

Comment: Does it throw any exception?

Answer (score 2):

The most likely reason is an incorrect path. I would recommend using an absolute path if you are unsure about your working directory.

Somewhat surprisingly, `File.Delete` does not give you an error if the file is not found (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884807/file-delete-doesnt-throw-error-when-the-file-doesnt-exist)).

You can use `File.Exists` to test if your path is correct.